# server not showing in runtime enviroment while adding server(tomcate) in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

tomcat server not showing in new server run time environment(windows>preference>server-> run time environment)
adding server in eclipse but it is not showing in list from the path discussed above

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- Help -> Install New Software
- Choose "Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios site
- Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
- Check JST Server Adapters (version 3.2.2)

Please change the download URL in step 2 according to the Eclipse version which you are using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Update Site URLs are listed at http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . You probably want the matching 'JST Server Adapters Extensions' feature.